# can i safely turn on my heat with my water not turned on in my house

Tags: radiant-heating, heat

i just moved into a hous3e and my water wont be turned on until next week but its cold in my house. I was wondering is it safe to turn my heat on. i have radiator heaters and i think they run off water some kind of way.im con fused and need answers

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but if your heating system is composed of hot water radiators, I would **NOT** turn it on until your water is on.

From what I know of these systems, even if they don't require new water to run, they still need to be plugged to the water system for when they need it.

For instance, right when you start to use them at the beginning of the cold season you need to bleed your radiators, which means you open a small valve and let the air come out.

Your system will need water to replace that air.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, you probably can and should turn the heat on.  The water in the heating system is independent of your drinking water supply (with the exception of a fill valve that adds fresh water to the system when needed).

What kind of heating/radiators do you have?  If you have an old house with cast iron steam radiators, the system will need additional fresh water more often - weekly or every few days in really cold weather. If so, you should probably wait until the water is turned on.  But assumning you have a closed loop hot water system like baseboard or radiators that have 2 pipes (in and out) - there should be water in the system and the heat should work.  Both systems should have a low-water cut off valve on them, so if there isn't water in the system, they shouldn't fire up.

One major caveat, if the house was "winterized" or vacant for a long time, someone may have intentialonally drained all the water out of the system so it wouldn't freeze.  In that case, or if you aren't sure, you should have the system checked first.

Your inspection report will probably tell you what kind of system you have and if it was operational when the inspection was done.